# Unwanted duplicate table results when merging two tables in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, join, duplicates

Problem: I'm trying create a query in SQLite that will display all the columns (stats) for a specific 'id' in table1 and join it with 2 separate results from table2.

When using a JOIN or a LEFT JOIN, I end up with the following result:
    (TABLE1 stats) + (TABLE2 skill1) + (TABLE1 stats) + (TABLE2 skill2)

Table 1 is duplicated twice because there are two skills in TABLE2. If there were 5 skills, I would get TABLE1 duplicated 5 times like above.

**What i want is:**
    (TABLE1 stats) + (TABLE2 SKILL1Bonus) + (TABLE2 SKILL2Bonus)

Table1 represents a category of a character with the key 'id'. Each character will have a different number of skill traits. Each skill trait is defined as (table2.skillID). The number of skill traits a character can have is up to 15. I'm trying to put together a query that will show base stats of character (table1.*) with all their bonuses from their skill traits (table2.bonus)

Example

```
-- Table 1 --
id = 8
strength = 12
agility = 11
```

... more stats

```
-- Table 2 --
id = 8
skillID = 3
bonus = 20% chance to dodge

id = 8
skillID = 4
bonus = 5% chance to crit
```

The closest I've gotten and what has got me the above result:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table1.id = 8;
```

Any help on the direction I should go would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure if subqueries would be a better route. Thanks!

Comment: What if there are more than two rows with same ID in table2? Put some rules and expected output *data* in the question

Comment: there are duplicates of the 'id' in table2 by design. The 'id' represents a category of character. It is the primary key in table1 and foreign key in table2.

Comment: What I am looking for is all of table1(where id=8) to be displayed along with both skills from table 2 (where id=8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  t1.id,
  t1.strength,
  t1.agility,
  group_concat(t2.skill,',') bonuses
from table1 t1
left outer join
table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id = 8
group by
  t1.id,
  t1.strength,
  t1.agility;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. This is much closer to what I want. I'll update the question. There can be any number of skills (up to 15). The min, max approach here will only work for two (like you said). Updating now...

Comment: you don't want to create 15 columns for that (or any more for that matter). Better keep each skill in separate row

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. I'm working with an already existing database that is huge. I'm still very new to SQL and I'm sure there is a good reason to having the skills fall into a different table to begin with. However, as it stands now, a character ID in table1 will have about 8 unique skill ID's in table2. Just trying to display that info as clean as possible.

Comment: How about all skills as comma separate values?

Comment: If there is a way to display all the "bonus"es from each "skillID" separated by commas that would be awesome. table1.*, table2.(all bonuses sep by commas)    :)

Comment: Just to be clear, I mean all the skillID's for that particular table1.id, which can be up to 15. But yeah, skills separated by commas works just fine

Comment: @dubba Updated my answer

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you so much. I am unable to upvote because I just created an account, rep is too low. Thank you though!